# How to share post on linkedin using swift 3?

Tags: swift

I tried the below code but it only opens the LinkedIn not share.

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn SDK in iOS using Swift.

I tried but it doesn't work. Please suggest me how I can share a post in LinkedIn.

```
@IBAction func linkbtn(_ sender: Any) {
    LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: [LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: {(sucess) in
        let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session
        print("Session ",session!)
        //let url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession(){
            let url: String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"

            let payloadStr: String = "{\"comment\":\"YOUR_APP_LINK_OR_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE\",\"visibility\":{\"code\":\"anyone\"}}"

            let payloadData = payloadStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, body: payloadData, success: { (response) in
                print(response!.data)
            }, error: { (error) in
                print(error!)

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "aomething went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

                alert.addAction(action)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }) {(error) in
        print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
 func shareOnLinkedIn(){
    LISDKSessionManager.createSession(withAuth: 
[LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true, successBlock: {(sucess) in
        let session = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session
        print("Session ",session!)
        //let url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession(){
            let url: String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"

            let payloadStr: String = "{\"comment\":\"YOUR_APP_LINK_OR_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_SHARE\",\"visibility\":{\"code\":\"anyone\"}}"

            let payloadData = payloadStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, body: payloadData, success: { (response) in
                print(response!.data)
            }, error: { (error) in
                print(error!)

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "aomething went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

                alert.addAction(action)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }) {(error) in
        print("Error \(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

Make sure you Have enabled w_share permission on your App Setting Authentication tab. and Added all the required Values on Info.plist

Comment: Very Well Explained.

Comment: am getting error in LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest . It says shared instance not found. Can you help ?

Comment: SDK Version which you are using in your project. Download the Latest version SDK using this :- https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#iossdk

Comment: How to enable share permission and what to add in info plist?